# Django ignoring my DATABASE_ENGINE setting -- sometimes

Tags: python, django, configuration

I've got several sites, each with a distinct settings file -- and with distinct names.  There's a floral theme to all the variant settings.  We have to keep the sites separate.

```
C:\Proj-Carnation> echo %DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE%
path.to.settings_carnation_win32
```

We have many test procedures which don't use the built-in `django-admin.py test` command because they're large batch jobs that are started by the Django front-end, and use the Django ORM.  We need to use the `django.db.connection.creation.create_test_db()` method to create a new  test database.

We've been using this test procedure for quite a while.  Currently, it's stopped working.  We've made numerous code structure changes, upgraded to Django 1.1.1 and Python 2.6.  All are possible culprits.

When I run Python I see this.

```
C:\Proj-Carnation> python
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71605, Apr 14 2009, 22:40:02) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.DATABASE_ENGINE
INSDIE django.db.__init__, settings.DATABASE_ENGINE=''
'sqlite3'
>>> import django.db
>>> django.db.connection
<django.db.backends.dummy.base.DatabaseWrapper object at 0x00EE88B0>
```

During the import of `django.db`, something the settings are clearly not set.  I added a print statement (with misspelled "INSIDE") in `django.db`.  The settings are not set.

Eventually, `settings.DATABASE_ENGINE` becomes `'sqlite3'`.  To an extend this "eventually" behavior is expected: the `settings` module uses a lazy loader technique.

The issue is this:  The connection -- built from incomplete settings -- is the `dummy` database backend.  Yet, the final settings show the engine to be `'sqlite3'`.

In another project (the "Root" Project), there are no issues.  Things work perfectly.  The DB settings create the proper sqlite3 backend instance.

So, what's different?  I'm stumped.  It's the environment settings or the physical directory trees are the top potential issues.

In the non-working `C:\Proj-Carnation`, the `PYTHONPATH` is `C:\Proj-Carnation;C:\Proj-Root;C:\This;C:\That`.

In the working root project `C:\Proj-Carnation`, the `PYTHONPATH` is `C:\Proj-Root;C:\This;C:\That`.

Am I looking for something in the "Carnation" project that has concealed something in the root project?  Sadly, the Carnation project only has a few files and they're in a package (`local`) which assures that they names distinct from the root project.

Is there some Django initialization in version 1.1.1 that's different?  For instance, is there something in `django.conf` that's out of whack with Python 2.6 and Django 1.1.1?

Is there some relative import issue that I've overlooked?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but this all seems very complex compared to what the typical Django project does. Could you provide a layout of your project(s) and app(s) and a description of how any projects are related?

Comment: @John Paulett:  It's a family of related web sites with batch back-end jobs.  So it is rather complex.

Answer (score 10):

Found it.

When your settings module is inside a package, the top-level `__init__.py` member of that package cannot import any Django material of any kind.

If the top-level `__init__.py` that contains your settings has a Django import, that Django import will (potentially) use the default settings before your settings are created.

And since some things in Django (like the database connection) are singletons, the thing that got created while reading your settings is the only one that can ever exist.

Do not put anything in the `__init__.py` in the package that contains settings modules.